# Getting information about motherboard on GNU/Linux

Tags: linux

If  am using a Linux operating system, how do I find

1. THe number of IOH chips in the system
2. The number of CPU's connected to each IOH chip
3. Whether the CPU's each have their own RAM or whether they all share RAM avaiable on the    machine.

If there is any way which gives all information about the motherboard on the system that would also be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [dmidecode](http://linux.die.net/man/8/dmidecode), to get information.
To get the motherboard name for example `dmidecode -s baseboard-product-name`
The SMBIOS command if available also can be used for some information.

Answer (score 1):

That information is available from the "DMI" subsystem ... but that is part of the BIOS, so quality varies.  On high quality machines, like IBM or SuperMicro servers it is usually pretty good.  On random desktops, random quality.

The `dmidecode` tool, usually packaged with the same name, can fish it out, or recent kernels expose it in sysfs directly; see `/sys/firmware/dmi` for it.